# How do I resolve placing template specializations before "instantiation" with GCC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have a set of templates where each base template has some large specializations and many of the other methods are mainly casts around types and constructors and operator=().  I made templates to factor out all those little methods as inlines and put the fat ones in the CPP files for a shared library. In windows it compiles and links fine into a DLL. It all does what I want on MSC but on GCC with the specialization code in the C++ file many of the specializations occur "after instantiation" with GCC.

Structurally the code is like the below.  (the real case is more messy) I'm not sure what I need to do as the template method declarations that call their superclass methods (from other templates) are where the method code is "instantiated" for their superclass templates.  What I need to do is somehow defer the instantiation until after the header declarations to happen in the .cpp file where the specialization's method bodies for the library are compiled.

```
// header file .h

template<class SubClassT, class CharT> 
class XBaseT
    : public YBaseT<char_object<CharT>>
{
    typedef XBaseT<XObject,CharT> super;
public:
    typedef char_object<CharT> ObjT; // seen by subclasses

    inline XBaseT() {}
    inline XBaseT(ObjT &p); // note no body, then intention is to have this specialization in library, not header.
    ...
};


template<> 
class XClass<XObject>
    : public XBaseT<XObject,char>
{
    typedef XBaseT<XObject,char> super;
public:
    inline XClass() {}
    inline XClass(ObjT &p) : super(p) {}
    ...
};

template<> 
class XObject
    : public ContainerT<XObject>
{
    typedef ContainerT<XObject> super;
public:
    inline XObject() {}
    static ContainerT<XObject> *static create(InitStruct &is);
    ...
};


// specializations in cpp file

tenplate<>
ContainerT<XObject> *
create(InitStruct &is) {
    // big code here needs to be in CPP file for library
}

// specialization for <XObject,char> happens "after instantiation" even thoght the method in it's template class is declared with no body.
template<>
XBaseT<XObject, char>::XBaseT(ObjT *p) {
    p_ = XObject::create(p);
}
```

The specialization just above in the.cpp file barfs on GCC as it is "after instantiation",
The instantiation in GCC happens when the "inline XClass(ObjT *p) : super(p) {}" constructor in XClass is declared. And that is so tiny I would like it to be inline as it should optimize out to nothing. On MSC the code is not instantiated until explicitly done so in the .cpp file. and the with MSC the linker seems to sort out what is needed and the compiler warns of missing methods declared but NOT instantiated there. In a declaration of

template class XBaseT;
template class ContainerT;
template class XClass;

The issues is some of the methods specialized for these templates are dependent on more than one of the templates and the specializations need to happen after the declarations.

How do I using "typename" or other template features get this for compile and link under CCC as opposed to windows MSC ?

Comment: What about removing `inline`? An inline function should be defined in every translation unit.

Comment: that is the objective for methods that do nothing but cast things as they would optimize to simply adding an offset to "this"